# debugging maven web application with intellijidea

Tags: maven, debugging, intellij-idea, wildfly

I need your help please to understand debugging a maven application using Wildfly and Intellij Idea.

Can anyone please explain to me how the debugging works, who handles that, the JVM, the IDE or the server ?
Well mabe not the server since we can debug a simple application without  using a server. but is it the JVM or the IDE. what is the relationship ?

I tryed the wildfly parameters 
-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=${myapp.jboss.port-offset}
agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8787
but this does not work.
when i set the suspend parameter to yes the application does not start at all.
what should i  also configure ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The JVM is run in debug mode by setting the following parameters

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

The Intelij IDE which holds the source code will then connect to the jvm on port 1044.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, steps :
1- I configured maven wildfly pluging using the given parameters to open a debugging port
2- created a remote debug configuration and specifiyed the debugger port settings
3 - then started the application using maven run,
4- and last started the debugger

Thanks for help